# procedure to dynamic sql

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic, procedure

I have a questions ,because I want use procedure in mysql example:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `scoreS`()
BEGIN
         PREPARE stmt FROM @scoreS;
           EXECUTE stmt;
           DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

and example code with this procedure:

```
  SET @results2 = 0;
    SET @scoreS = CONCAT("SELECT CommentsId INTO @results2 FROM `",tableName,"`  WHERE CRC32 = ",Crc32," ORDER BY CommentsId DESC LIMIT 1");
    CALL scoreS();
```

I want use this procedure instead:

```
SET @results2 = 0;
           SET @scoreS = CONCAT("SELECT CommentsId INTO @results2 FROM `",tableName,"` WHERE CRC32 = ",Crc32," ORDER BY CommentsId DESC LIMIT 1");
           PREPARE stmt FROM @scoreS;
           EXECUTE stmt;
           DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

And now I dont know when I use this procedure action will be faster in adding records ??

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on procedural SQL code in MySQL or otherwise but I expect there would be very little different in performance between those two approaches (assuming that the scoreS procedure is only created the once).

What I would say though is that a lot of the value in the PREPARE statement is in being able to re-use the prepared query with different parameters and not incur the cost of re-processing the SQL statement. Since you're not doing this (you're not using parameterisation and are just  destroying the prepared query immediately), is there much point in using PREPARE? (Of course, I may just be showing my ignorance by assuming you can execute queries some other way than using PREPARE and EXECUTE from inside a procedure!)